# Unable to set temperature of AC_UNIT device

Tags: google-smart-home, google-assistant

i have some trouble in control device from google assistant. I have synced 2 devices to google assistant, only have diffence in ids and names, just like this

```json
{
    "payload":{
        "devices":[
            {
                "id":"FtxvyT43euwCPT4b7pVzam-d113a8cb2ccb4f6ba9e4831cb90a7695",
                "type":"action.devices.types.AC_UNIT",
                "traits":[
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
                    "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting",
                    "action.devices.traits.FanSpeed",
                    "action.devices.traits.Modes"
                ],
                "name":{
                    "defaultNames":[
                        "西蒙电气"
                    ],
                    "name":"I7温控器中弘",
                    "nicknames":[
                        "i7-温控器-中弘"
                    ]
                },
                "willReportState":false,
                "attributes":{
                    "availableFanSpeeds":{
                        "speeds":[
                            {
                                "speed_name":"auto",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "auto",
                                            "automatic"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"low",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "low",
                                            "slow"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"medium",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "medium"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"high",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "high",
                                            "fast"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "ordered":true
                    },
                    "availableModes":[
                        {
                            "name":"mode",
                            "name_values":[
                                {
                                    "name_synonym":[
                                        "mode"
                                    ],
                                    "lang":"en"
                                }
                            ],
                            "settings":[
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"Sleep",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "sleep"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"Airsupply",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "airsupply",
                                                "air supply"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "ordered":true
                        }
                    ],
                    "availableThermostatModes":[
                        "heat",
                        "cool"
                    ],
                    "thermostatTemperatureUnit":"C"
                },
                "deviceInfo":{
                    "manufacturer":"西蒙电气",
                    "model":"I7温控器中弘",
                    "hwVersion":"1.0",
                    "swVersion":"2.0"
                },
                "customData":{}
            },
            {
                "id":"bYJDj2XYve3yLKPUnjNCp3-bbb06180c6c647738b3eb12e3d474e71",
                "type":"action.devices.types.AC_UNIT",
                "traits":[
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
                    "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting",
                    "action.devices.traits.FanSpeed",
                    "action.devices.traits.Modes"
                ],
                "name":{
                    "defaultNames":[
                        "西蒙电气"
                    ],
                    "name":"I7中央空调",
                    "nicknames":[
                        "i7-中央空调"
                    ]
                },
                "willReportState":false,
                "attributes":{
                    "availableFanSpeeds":{
                        "speeds":[
                            {
                                "speed_name":"auto",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "auto",
                                            "automatic"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"low",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "low",
                                            "slow"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"medium",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "medium"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name":"high",
                                "speed_values":[
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym":[
                                            "high",
                                            "fast"
                                        ],
                                        "lang":"en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "ordered":true
                    },
                    "availableModes":[
                        {
                            "name":"mode",
                            "name_values":[
                                {
                                    "name_synonym":[
                                        "mode"
                                    ],
                                    "lang":"en"
                                }
                            ],
                            "settings":[
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"Sleep",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "sleep"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"Airsupply",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "airsupply",
                                                "air supply"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "ordered":true
                        }
                    ],
                    "availableThermostatModes":[
                        "heat",
                        "cool"
                    ],
                    "thermostatTemperatureUnit":"C"
                },
                "deviceInfo":{
                    "manufacturer":"西蒙电气",
                    "model":"I7中央空调",
                    "hwVersion":"1.0",
                    "swVersion":"2.0"
                },
                "customData":{}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When i say something like `set aircondition temperature to 22℃`, 'i7-中央空调' returns a success, but 'i7-温控器-中弘' shows **'not support this mode'**. So what cause it? And, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `WillReportState = true` since you do not have `commandOnlyTemperatureSetting = true`. You either need to specify the device cannot report state and is `commandOnly` or have the devices report state. Check out the [`TemperatureSetting` trait attributes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting) for more details.

If you're still having issues after that update, check your[logs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging) to identify the particular issue for that device.

Comment: thanks a lot. set `commandOnlyTemperatureSetting = true` solved my problem.